# HTTPPostedFileBase always return null in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, httppostedfilebase

I have checked various answer for this, but none of them works for me, my code in .cshtml is as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="PostedNRLFile" />
```

and then in controller I have

```
 public JsonResult SaveRecord(NewAuditLetterViewModel viewModel, FormCollection all, string hvalue, HttpPostedFileBase PostedNRLFile)
```

Which is always null, Please help me in this.

I have already tried few things like creating a property in viewmodel, this is also null.
Also used  `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "documentForm" }` in my beginform tag.
Also checked their is only one  tag in source.

Comment: Show the `BeginForm()` code in your view.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRecord", "EditNewAuditLetter", FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))

Comment: You should edit your question! But what you have shown will work fine. I assume you are doing a normal submit and not using ajax?

Comment: The fact your method is returning `JsonResult` suggests you are using ajax to post the form, it which case this wont work at all. Edit you question to make it clear what you are actually doing

Comment: Thanks, Stephan, I will modify my code as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in form tag.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
                               new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Try this c# code in controller action

```
if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

You have to retrieve the file.

Comment: OP has `HttpPostedFileBase PostedNRLFile` as a parameter in the method so `if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0) { ..}` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use MVC to upload file you need:
- create form and have to set tag: **enctype = "multipart/form-data"**
- create input with **name same HttpPostedFileBase in controller**

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```cs
var fileCount = Request.Files.Count;
if (fileCount > 0)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < (fileCount); i++)
    { 
        HttpPostedFileBase Yourfile= Request.Files[i] as   HttpPostedFileBase;
        // do whatever with your file
    }
}
```

Comment: If using parameter `HttpPostedFileBase PostedNRLFile` does not work, then this certainly wont.